# Lat Lon to X Y, literal projection zoom level

Tags: javascript, canvas, gpx

Following this tutorial: https://macwright.org/2015/08/31/canvas-animations-on-maps.html

I want to map a series of lat long coordinates I recorded during a hike onto a 360x180px canvas.

The tutorial gives this formula:

```
var x = longitude + 180;
var y = 90 - latitude;
```

The problem is, all the dots are drawing on top of each other because (I'm guessing) the lat lon decimals are basically the same until the 100,000th decimal place.

How can I 'zoom' in, or map to the extents of what I recorded on my hike?

5 sample points:

```
[21.442751, -157.824244],
[21.442773, -157.824226],
[21.442787, -157.824168],
[21.442817, -157.824158],
[21.442886, -157.824173],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One strategy is to treat the latitude and longitude as cartesian coordinates, which works for decimal degrees over short distance but has scaling issues in higher latitudes where 1° latitude is much bigger than 1° longitude. Fixing this scale error isn't too hard over short distances (use the sine of the latitude).

Start by getting the bounding rectangle of the coordinates, then subtract the lower left corner from the other coordinates to get the dimensions of a minimum bounding rectangle.

To fit coordinates in decimal degrees into a box in pixels, scale the values to fit in the box.

In this case, the rectangle will be:

1. Lower left (smallest lat, smallest long): 21.442751, -157.824244
2. Upper right (biggest lat, biggest long): 21.442886, -157.824158

The rectangle may use coordinates from up to 4 different points.

That produces a diff lat (height) of 0.000135 and diff long (width) of 0.000086 degrees.

Getting the scale factors to fit to a 360 x 180 px rectangle (assuming 360 wide by 180 high) gives:

1. Height: 180 ÷ 0.000135 = 1,333,333
2. Width: 360 ÷ 0.000086 = 4,186,046

Assuming you want to keep the result in proportion, use the same factor both dimensions, otherwise the other dimension won't fit in the box, so:

- scaleFactor = 1333333;

To get the x, y coordinates for each point in pixels from the bottom left corner, use:

- y coord: (lat.posA - lat.lowerLeft) * scale;
- x coord: (lon.posA - lon.lowerLeft) * scale;

The last thing to do is to calculate the pixel coordinates from the top left corner, with the vertical dimension y increasing down and the horizontal dimension x increasing to the right. The x coords are already OK, you just need to subtract the y coord from 180.

So points become (noting lat, long is transformed to x, y):

1. (21.442751, -157.824244) => (0, 180)
2. (21.442773, -157.824226) => (24, 151)
3. (21.442787, -157.824168) => (101, 132)
4. (21.442817, -157.824158) => (114, 92)
5. (21.442886, -157.824173) => (94, 0)

where (0,0) is the top left corner of the box.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 360px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.A {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 180px;
}
.B {
  position: absolute;
  left: 24px;
  top: 151px;
}
.C {
  position: absolute;
  left: 101px;
  top: 132px;
}
.D {
  position: absolute;
  left: 114px;
  top: 92px;
}
.E {
  position: absolute;
  left: 94px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="A">1</span>
  <span class="B">2</span>
  <span class="C">3</span>
  <span class="D">4</span>
  <span class="E">5</span>
</div>
```

Additional work is to centre the coordinates in the box, I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct. Since your hike all occurred in a very small portion of the world, it is not helpful to plot it on a map of the world. You can effectively zoom and center your hike coordinates like so:

`var x = (longitude + 157.82425) * 10000 * 360;`

`var y = (21.4429 - latitude) * 6000 * 180;`